# Creating drop down menu on top menu issue in joomla 1.5.11

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, joomla

I'm new in using joomla. Now I have website that runs on Joomla 1.5.11 and I want some minor modification on it. What I want to do is on the **`top menu`** I want to put some drop down menu onHover and I follow this procedure:

`http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=345396`

and this video tutorial: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVhS1-7edIQ`

but the result is this: `http://postimg.org/image/rhut3a3nt/`

As you can see on the top image the **SUB MENU**(which is the **`CONTACT US`**) is displayed on top level menu( on the right side of main menu) but when I click the **CONTACT US** menu it actually a sub menu(please see the breadcrumbs bottom image) in **`ABOUT US`** menu.

Am I missing some configuration for this? I'm really sure that I followed the procedures I viewed. Here's the screenshot of my dashboard:

```
http://postimg.org/image/ic0l7jprr/

http://postimg.org/image/ceiqt0ooj/

http://postimg.org/image/6l6l22hul/
```

Any help and alternatives is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: define start Level and End Level in Module section

Comment: I already did sir.. but its the same. Do you have any ideas sir?